# How to distinguish end-user scroll of an android ScrollView from programatic scrolling?

Tags: android, scrollview

**Background:** I have a ScrollView / TextView pair that receives an intermittent stream of text from an external source. It automatically scrolls to the bottom on each update.

I'd like for the user to be able to break out of that auto scroll down mode by manually scrolling to somewhere, however I am unclear how to distinguish the manual scroll from the programatic scroll I am doing myself.

My UI update runs on a timer to buffer redraws:

```
private Handler outputUpdater = new Handler ();
private static String outputBuffer = "";
private static boolean outputHasChanged = false;
private static final Object lock = new Object ();

private Runnable outputUpdaterTask = new Runnable () {
    public void run () {
        synchronized (lock) {

            // if the output has changed, update the TextView
            if (outputHasChanged) {
                TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView);
                tv.setText (outputBuffer);
            }

            // if the output has changed, or the scroll hasn't reached the bottom yet
            // then keep scrolling down
            if (outputHasChanged || !scrollAtBottom ()) {
                ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) findViewById (R.id.scrollView);
                sv.fullScroll (View.FOCUS_DOWN);
            }

            outputHasChanged = false;
        }

        outputUpdater.postDelayed (this, 100);
    }
};
```

`scrollAtBottom` gets it's value from a `onScrollChanged` handler.

This all works fine. It's necessary to call `fullScroll` even if there was no text update because a single call to `fullScroll` doesn't always go to the bottom if there are TextView updates going on, or the virtual keypad visibility changed, etc.

I'd like that if the user manually scrolls, that I could know to make a decision to stop calling `fullScroll`.

Unfortunately It's seems that not enough simply to treat any transition from "at the bottom, automatic mode" to "not at the bottom" as a cue to switch to manual mode because various UI changes seem to move the scroll view off the bottom also (e.g. virtual keypad showing).

**Question Restated:**
How can I distinguish the user initiated scroll from the programatic scroll?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you tried using a `boolean` with `onTouchEvent`, something similar to:

```
boolean userIntercept = false;
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
    int action = me.getAction();
    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            userIntercept = true;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(me);
}
```

then in your `outputUpdaterTask`:

```
// if the output has changed, or the scroll hasn't reached the bottom yet
// then keep scrolling down
if (outputHasChanged || !scrollAtBottom () && !userIntercept) {
    ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) findViewById (R.id.scrollView);
    sv.fullScroll (View.FOCUS_DOWN);
}
```

You would just need to determine a way in which you can return the `userIntercept` to `false`, whichever best fits your application.

Comment: Thanks, that's the basic idea that works. For completeness, what I'm doing now is: ACTION_MOVE or ACTION_DOWN start manual mode and turn on a "finger down" state. ACTION_UP turns the "finger down" state off. onScrollChanged and ACTION_UP both turn on automatic scrolling again if finger state and atBottom are both true.

Comment: it's necessary to break out of manual mode in the onScrollChanged based on the finger state because you can "flick" the screen to scroll, and you get the ACTION_UP before the scrolling finished.